# JMeter doesn't use passed properties

Tags: jmeter

I call JMeter via cmd:

```
jmeter -t C:\Users\patryk\Desktop\webSocketTest.jmx -l D:\jmeter_result\req_5000\len_2500-user_1000\results.jtl -JRequests=5000 -JDataLen=2500 -JUsers=1000 -e -o D:\jmeter_result\req_5000\len_2500-user_1000\report
```

I have defined variables like on screenshot, and I use them in my tests. LogViewer indicates that I passed 0 as a number of users (threads).

```
2024-03-05 00:35:48,154 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2024-03-05 00:35:48,154 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2024-03-05 00:35:48,161 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group .net
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 0 threads for group Thread Group .net.
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=0 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2024-03-05 00:35:48,163 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Why?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) and the below test plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.2">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${users}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="users" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">users</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(Users,1)}</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </Arguments>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

The command used is simplified to:

```
jmeter -JUsers=2 -n -t test.jmx
```

If you still experience the issue perhans something is wrong with your JMeter installation. To troubleshoot the issue you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)

Otherwise you can just reinstall "clean" JMeter and compare it with your installation.